# ndk-gdb can't find source line numbers

Tags: android, gdb, android-ndk

I'm using the ndk-gdb to debug some native code on the Android platform. However, the debugger seems to be unable to find source line numbers and source files. I get warnings and errors like this:

```
warning: shared library handler failed to enable breakpoint
0xaff0c184 in ?? ()
```

and

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x80e030a8 in ?? ()
```

That's not very useful at all... It seems to me that the problem must be in the file and line-number look-up, but as I am quite new to native programming for Android, I'm kinda stuck here. So can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Any help would be very much appreciated!

**Edit 1**:
I'm using the NDK r7b on Windows and call the `ndk-build` script with the following options:

```
$NDK/ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug V=1
```

The APP_OPTIM=debug setting is a modification to the ndk-build script that should disable the stripping of debug symbols as per [these](http://vilimpoc.org/blog/2010/09/23/hello-gdbserver-a-debuggable-jni-example-for-android/) instructions.

**Edit 2**:
I have not solved this problem, but worked around it by switching to using the NDK on Ubuntu linux. It kinda feels like surrendering to the NDK but time and again the linux-roots of the Android platform made developing native code for it on Windows feel unnatural and clumsy.

Kind regards,

Jonas

Comment: Hi Jonas, what commands do you use to build your native code and what NDK version are you using?

Comment: Hi Martin, I've added the NDK version and build command to my original post.